# Implementing compareTo() method in a Generic class

Tags: java, generics

I have a project I'm working on and this is what I have started with:

```
public class Pair<T extends Comparable, E extends Comparable> implements Comparable{

    private E e;
    private T t;

    public int compareTo(Pair arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

I need to use this class to sort ordered pairs in ascending order. If the first ones are equal, then it should sort by the send point.

Could you guys please help me get a start on this?

Comment: Please feel free to edit your own question, but please don't ruin the formatting that I've given to your code.

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't figure out how to do that. I'm new to this forum.

Answer (score 8):

In your class definition, your `T` and `E` generics lack the comparison against themselves. This also happens for your `Pair` class. The definition of the class should be:

```
public class Pair<T extends Comparable<T>, E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<Pair<T, E>> {

}
```

Now you can define how to compare the pair. Here's an example:

```
public class Pair<T extends Comparable<T>, E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<Pair<T, E>> {
    private E e;
    private T t;

    public int compareTo(Pair<T, E> pair) {
        int result = t.compareTo(pair.t);
        return (result == 0) ? e.compareTo(pair.e) : result;
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to make sense. There's a line in the specification that says: "The compareTo() method for the Pair class will need to make use of the compareTo() methods of the type variables E and T." Just to make sure, that is just referring to what you already did inside the compareTo() method, correct?

Comment: for best results, use `T extends Comparable<? super T>`, and same for `E`